# Simplify SQL query of multiple SELECT statements, each with UNION and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, union, sql-limit

Need assistance with simplifying this SQL query to possibly a single SELECT:

```
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 1
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 2
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 4
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 5
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 6
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 8
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 9
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 10
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id = 17
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 10)
```

I've been told to try using GROUP BY and HAVING. However, any query I tried didn't work in the slightest...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - apologies, forgot to mention database engine is MySQL

Comment: It is a single select already, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can condense this down with a window function to limit each group bucket to 10.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY(category_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS GroupOrder
    FROM `deals`
    WHERE category_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
)AS X
WHERE
    GroupOrder<=10
```

Comment: You did not mention your RDMS. If MySQL then this article discusses how to emulate ROW_NUMBER. https://www.log4code.com/alternative-to-row_number-in-mysql/

Comment: Note that if you're using MySQL, you must be using MySQL 8.0 or later to have access to the ROW_NUMBER() function.  For MariaDB, you must be using 10.2.0 or later.  Most other RDBMSs have had this function for many years.

Comment: I think this works out too , rank if not row_number may work too.... just one thing Ross forgot the category_id = 17, Assuming he didnt scroll down the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I need to know if you need that limit of 10, is this like take top 10 of all those things?

if not then

```
SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE category_id between 0 and 10 or category_id=17
ORDER BY category_id asc,  id desc
```

Comment: The limit is completely necessary but would be nice to include. It's exactly like that, pulling top 10 items from the table

Comment: Do you have another field that counts them or something like that ? that way we could use it to keep the top 10....SELECT * FROM `deals`
WHERE id > 11 and  (category_id between 0 and 10 or category_id=17)
ORDER BY category_id asc,  id desc

Comment: maybe use rank... where RANK ( ) OVER ( partition by category_id order by id desc ) < 10

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of MySQL without the windowing functions, here is the code.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Category_ID, T1.Name
FROM (
SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=concat_ws('',t.Category_ID),@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
         ,t.*
         ,@prev_value := concat_ws('',t.Category_ID)
    FROM data t,
         (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
         (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
   ORDER BY t.Category_ID
   ) T1
  WHERE T1.RowNumber < 10
  AND T1.Category_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

You will need to add the necessary field names to the other select.

This uses the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)